# How to change point color only in scatter 3d plot using R?

Tags: r, colors, point, scatter3d

I tried change point color to black in scatter3d plot using R, but failed.
It is difficult to view data because the color of the point and the surface color overlap.

Could i get some ideas?

```
# scatter plot with regression plane
scatter3D(x, y, z, pch = 16, cex = 1,  alpha.col = 0.8, color="black", col = ramp.col(c("dark green", "khaki", "dark red")), bty="b2", 
          theta = 595, phi = 35, ticktype = "detailed", d=200,
          xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab = "",  
          surf = list(x = x.pred, y = y.pred, z = z.pred,  
                      facets=T, border="black"), main = "Room A")
```

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow your command with `points3D` and include `add=TRUE`.

```
# scatter plot with regression plane
scatter3D(x, y, z,  
          col = ramp.col(c("dark green", "khaki", "dark red")), bty="b2", 
          theta = 595, phi = 35, ticktype = "detailed", d=200,
          xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab = "",  
          surf = list(x = x.pred, y = y.pred, z = z.pred,  
                      facets=T, border="black"), main = "Room A")

points3D(x, y, z, pch = 16, color="black", alpha = 0.8, add=TRUE)
```